Wrong theorem enumeration: "Theorem Appendix A.1"
I am preparing a manuscript in the journal style ws-ijnt (see worldscientific.com/page/ijnt/stylefiles-readme-2e). The numbering of the theorems in the appendix looks strange: we get, for example, Theorem Appendix A.1, rather than Theorem A.1. How to solve this?
\documentclass{ws-ijnt}
\begin{document}

\appendix
\section{First section of the appendix}
\begin{theorem}
My Theorem
\end{theorem}

\end{document}


Where do you get the file ws-ijnt.cls ?

Added a link to the question.

I think you should write the journal and ask. In their class \appendix adds the word Appendix to the \thesection command and theorems are numnbered as \thesection.\thetheorem (or something similar). The presumably add this prefix as an easy way to get \section{Foo} to say Appendix A Foo. At least they do redefine \theequation.

A fast fix would be \renewcommand\thetheorem{\Alph{section}.\arabic{theorem}} after \appendix

Thank you very much! I would accept your comments as an answer (if you could post them as such).

That class does some interesting things with \appendix:
\newcommand\appendix{\par
    \refstepcounter{appendix}
    \setcounter{section}{0}%
    \renewcommand\thesection{\appendixname\ \Alph{section}}
    \renewcommand\thesubsection{\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\if@noseceq
    \renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{equation}}
\else
    \setcounter{equation}{0}
    \@addtoreset{equation}{section}
    \renewcommand\theequation{\Alph{section}.\arabic{equation}}
\fi
}%

This means that now \thesection will be Appendix A, Appendix B etc instead of just being the numbering.
But they also define the theorem env as
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
(all other predefined theorem structures reuse the theorem counter)
which means that the theorem is numbered as \thesection.\arabic{theorem}. So when you add Appendix to \thesection, that also appears in the theorem numbering.
Quick fix
\appendix
% class has an error: prefixing \thesection with \appendixname, 
% makes `\appendixname` show up in the numbering of theorems
% listed in the appendix
\renewcommand\thetheorem{\Alph{section}.\arabic{theorem}}

I would also ask the journal about this, as you are probably not the only one with this issue.
